# Problem with assigning variable C#

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch

When I return the string timeTaken, it is null, and it says this on the IDE to, although it has been defined in the main method (TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;)

```
class Program
{    
    public static string timeTaken;    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);    
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();               
        using (var response = request.GetResponse());
        timer.Stop();    
        TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I output timeTaken?

Comment: "When I return the string..." Code not return string anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a local variable with the same name

```
TimeSpan timeTaken
```

which hides your static class field.

To output the value of timer.Elapsed you could write something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", timer.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Surely this would fail without `ToString()` ?

Comment: @CodeBlend: No it won't. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

There is two timeTaken variable, one local to rthe Main function, the other one is a static member of the class. To explicitly refer to the string one use `Program.timeTaken`. Anyway is better if you refactor the code to have different names.

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake: you define the variable "timeTaken" once again inside `static void Main(...)` on the line

```
TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
```

This will shadow the static definition. To get back to the static class field use

```
Program.timeTaken = ...
```

think about naming (for example name your static field `_timeTaken`
or just use

```
timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
```

instead of

```
TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
```

Comment: There is no "this" with static

Comment: He can't use this. because the field is static. He can only use Program.timeTaken to access the static field.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something more like this:-

```
class Program
{
  public static string timeTaken;
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    timer.Stop();
    timeTaken = timer.Elapsed.ToString();
  }
}
```